# MySQL: Query on another query result and return both results?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am using following 'php' and 'MySQL' code to list most recent topics from my database and to list related titles below each of those titles...

```
// First Query 
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table  ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,20");  
$result = mysql_query($query) 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "Main Topic: ".$row['title'];
$main_title = $row['title'];
    echo "Related to this Topic:";

   // Second Query 
    $related_query= mysql_query("
    SELECT * MATCH (title)
    AGAINST('$main_title'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)AS 
    score FROM my_table  MATCH(title)  AGAINST('$main_title'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
    HAVING score > 10  ORDER BY score DESC
    ");  
    $related_result = mysql_query($related_query) 

            while($related_row = mysql_fetch_array($related_result)){
            echo  "<br>". $related_row['title'];
    }


}
```

This works fine. But the problem is that it uses a MySQL queries within a loop. (second query runs 20 times) I've read it is not a good programming practice because it uses server resources heavily.

So, is there a way to do this with just one query or two queries without having to run a query within a loop?

Thank you

Comment: Can't you store all the $main_titles in one array and then use the "IN" operation in the second query with all the $main_titles array?

Comment: @costa in that case, there are two questions.. 1. Can I use IN operation in full text search?  2. If I'm using IN operation, it will return all rows related to ALL main titles as a bulk. But I want related titles for EACH main title SEPARATELY..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, STOP USING `mysql_*()` functions. They have been deprecated for years.

Second, once you start using a reasonable database interface like PDO or even just mysqli, you can do prepared queries. The query can be prepared outside the loop, which will save resources and reduce the time taken.

Third, it's possible this could be done with one query, but would need DB structure posted to be certain.

EDIT: here's some untested PDO code:

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database", "user", "pass");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * MATCH (title) AGAINST (? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score FROM my_table MATCH (title) AGAINST (? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) HAVING score > 10  ORDER BY score DESC");

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    echo "Main Topic: $row[title]";
    $params = array($row["title"], $row["title"]);
    $result2 = $stmt->execute($params);
    $result2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch()) {
        echo  "<br>$row2[title]";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. i'll try it and let you know... i'm totally new to PDO, so i have to learn the basics first.. anyway which is better: PDO or MySQLi?

Comment: For things like prepared queries I find PDO is much more intuitive. In the example above, using mysqli, you'd have to bind parameter variables to the query, and specify if they were strings or integers, and then bind another set of variables to the result set before you could use it. PDO is a database abstraction layer and takes away a lot of the low level stuff. Also PDO is database agnostic, so if you change to Postgres or Oracle your code doesn't need to be changed.